# Empty Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I created an object which contains an array.
I noticed that when I dont enter any values into the array, it still has one - its size,
So how can I check if the array is actually empty?

Here's how I'm creating the array:

```
array = { text:[10] }
```

Comment: @123456: In future, to clarify or improve your question, use the "edit" link under it rather than comments. I've moved your comment into the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the array is not an array entry (aka [array "element"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4)). It *is* a property, `length`, but it's not an entry. An empty array is exactly that: empty.

The code you posted in a comment:

```
array = { text:[10] }
```

does not create an empty array. It creates an array of length `1` with the entry `10` in it.

If you want to create an *empty* array with a specific length, you can't do that in a single statement with an array literal (`[]`). You have two ways you can do it:

Using an array literal and assigning to `length`:

```
var a = [];
a.length = 10;
```

or using `new Array`:

```
var a = new Array(10);
```

But there's virtually never any reason, in JavaScript, to predefine the length of the array, because standard JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). It does make sense with the new *typed* arrays (`Uint32Array` and such), and to do it you have to use the array constructor (`new Uint32Array(10)`).

Comment: I use the length property to check it the array is empty - and i get 1 even when i didnt enter any value

Comment: @123456: I just saw your comment on the question and updated: You **are** putting an entry (10) in that array.

Comment: I'm new to javascript - so i didnt know that.
It doesnt define the size?

Comment: @123456: Nope, it defines its contents. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is an array with four entries. I've expanded the answer to show how they work.

Comment: Thank you!
it realy helped me